# jQuery ajax get: dataType html fails with 200 OK

Tags: html, jquery

There are many similar questions, but I didn't find one that gets straight to the point: I'm trying to get some plain text from jQuery $.ajax call using DataType html. StatusCode is 200 OK but error function is fired.

---

Code time:

### HTML (index.html)

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function doajax(){
   $.ajax({
   url:'http://localhost/test.php',
   DataType:'html',
   data:{id:5},
   success:function(data){ alert('We made it'); },
   error:function(v1,v2,v3){ alert('Something went wrong'); } //gets fired
  });
 }
 </script>
 <a href="#" onclick="doajax(); return false;">Click to test</a>
</body>
</html>
```

### PHP (test.php)

```
echo 'Hi';
```

Now this looks trivial to me, but I can't get data from the test.php file.
Just "Hi" string is expected, but I get error handler fired and nothing is even returned:

### ERROR RESPONSES

```
xhr:status 200
status:error
text:-blank-
```

Why can't I get this easy script to work?

EDIT: missing comma

UPDATE: IT'S A Firefox PROBLEM! ALL BROWSERS WORK BUT IT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out: I was sending ajax request to `http://localhost` while opened testing page was `http://192.168.1.110`, AKA my own local IP address. By that of course Javascript "Same origin policy" made the mess and broke the request.

Changed ajax request to `http://192.168.1.110` and all goes great now.

Answer (score 1):

code is fine but, you've missed comma (`,`) after `data:{id:5}`

so it should be `data:{id:5},` rather than `data:{id:5}`

Comment: oops, typo writing post! Edited, thank you. But it still doesn't work, even if so simple...

Comment: May Be Another error, the code is working fine as i've tested it.

Comment: Did you test it with Firefox? It came out was a Firefox-only problem

Comment: yes, it works in all browsers like firefox, chrome, IE. if this is live project then provide link of this page.

Comment: Ok, I got it while putting online to let you try: "Same Origin Policy" is the reason of everything...I'll answer the question...thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but the fix was slightly different.

I was making a get request with

```
JQueryAjaxSettings ={
    url: '/api/Cart/',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "application/json"
};
```

As it turns out providing the datatype to the get request resulted in the error being called. Simply remove `datatype: "application/json"` and it works.